# Is it possible to use SVM to learn a training sample with an input of "Feature Matrix" rather than a "Feature Vector"?

Tags: xml, classification, svm, document-classification, feature-selection

Is it possible to use SVM to learn a training sample with an input of "Feature Matrix" rather than a "Feature Vector" ? I need to classify XML documents by representing each document as a Feature Matrix. Typically, a feature vector is used to train SVM for text classification. However, representing XML documents as feature vectors could lead to  structural information loss!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard practice is to create "long vectors" by "rasterizing" the matrix.

Ultimately, SVMs resolve into lines or hyperplanes, not polygons.

Comment: Sounds reasonable! Thanks :)